# In GWT, is it possible to scale an image widget to smaller than its original size?

Tags: css, image, gwt, widget

I am wondering if it is possible to shrink an image widget down to a size that is smaller than the image resource itself.  I have tried the following:

```
imageResource.setSize(size, size);
imageResource.setPixelSize(size, size);
```

I have also tried re-sizing in the CSS file.  But when I size the image to smaller than the original, it just crops it down and doesn't actually shrink it.  It seems to me the solution is to use a high resolution, smaller image that I can scale up if need be, but I feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: You can try with the Canvas object and work with vectors. Any image and any other vector asset in your Canvas can be manipulated Greatly. Try the GWT Canvas class or gwt-graphics (I have used the later with great results)

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone.  I solved the problem by using a `Data Resource` rather than an `Image Resource` for my images.  This cleared it up without changing any of my other code.  This answer was of course on SO already, but I must have overlooked it since I was searching for a solution for days to no avail.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3 background-size property to scale the image:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Note that it's not supported in some very old browsers.

Comment: I am able to scale the image, the problem is when I try to scale the image smaller than the image resource.  It will scale down to the original size of the image resource, then it will start to crop rather than scale any further.  So if I have an image that is 100px X 100px and I try to set the size at 50px X 50px, I get the top-left quarter of the image rather than the entire image shrunk down to a quarter of its original size.

Comment: If you set an image as a background, you can scale it up or down as much as you like. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/s6bDu/  The original image is 540 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with,

```
ImageResorce myImage = new ImageResource();
myImage.getElement().setAttribute("height","20px");
myImage.getElement().setAttribute("width","20px");
```

cheers !!!